How to remove brackets around a publication year?
In the following MWE, I'd like to remove the parentheses around the publication year in its formatted bibliographic entry. A comma should be inserted before the publication year. How to do it?
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-verbose, articlein=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]   {title}{#1\isdot}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@Article{Chiantaretto2005,
author = {Chiantaretto, Jean-François}, 
title = {À propos de la première transgression}, 
journal = {Topique}, 
volume = {92}, 
number = {3}, 
pages = {111--125}, 
year = {2005}, 
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text here \autocite{Chiantaretto2005}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}


You wrote, "I'd like to remove [the parentheses] around the publication year". Please clarify whether this pertains to the citation call-out, the formatted bibliographic entry, or both.

Please also clarify if any symbol -- say, a comma -- should be inserted before the publication year.

You already know how to insert the comma from @Alan Munn's answer, why include this again in this question?

You can change the format of the issuedate field like this:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-verbose, articlein=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareFieldFormat{issuedate}{#1}
\renewcommand*{\volnumdatedelim}{\addcomma\space}% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/724306/36296
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]   {title}{#1\isdot}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@Article{Chiantaretto2005,
author = {Chiantaretto, Jean-François}, 
title = {À propos de la première transgression}, 
journal = {Topique}, 
volume = {92}, 
number = {3}, 
pages = {111--125}, 
year = {2005}, 
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text here \autocite{Chiantaretto2005}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}


